Does the convex conjugate preserve little o relations
Let $f,g : [0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ be convex functions with both $x =o(f(x))$ and $x=o(g(x))$.
Then their convex conjugates $f^*,g^*: [0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ are (well-)defined by
$$
    f^*(y) = \sup_{x \geq 0} \{xy-f(x)\}
$$
$$
    g^*(y) = \sup_{x \geq 0} \{xy-g(x)\}
$$
If additionally $f(x) = o(g(x))$, does $f^*(y) = o(g^*(y))$ also hold? (All little o relations are at $+\infty$.)
This seems hard to prove using the definitions.
One would need to show that for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ there exists some $y_n$ such that for all $y \geq y_n$ holds that
$$
\frac{\sup_{x \geq 0} \{xy-f(x)\}}{\sup_{x \geq 0} \{xy-g(x)\}}\leq \frac{1}{n}
$$

No.
The conjugate of $f(x) = \frac1p x^p$ for $p>1$ is given by $f^*(y) = \frac1q x^q$, where $\frac1p + \frac1q=1$.
Now take $f(x) = x^4$ and $g(x) = x^5$, then $\frac{ f(x) }{ g(x) } \to 0$ for $x\to \infty$ but $ \frac{ f^*(x) }{ g^*(x) } \to \infty$ for $x\to \infty$

This was a bit of a silly question on my end, since convex conjugation reverses the ordering, of course, but one might hope for $g^* = o(f^*)$. But your answer is perfect for the question as is!
